# SignalR Group message application, creating group message box causes refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .net, signalr

I am working on creating a chat application using SignalR and I know my code is causing the session to refresh however I cannot see where it is causing this. Whenever I hit my Submit input tag it goes through the steps of creating a chat box just like the private chat(which works). However, it does not call out to the server for sendGroupMessage method in order to send the chat. Once it is out of the createGroupChatWindow function on the javascript side it will refresh and disconnect the user.

Any advice on to why this is happening or pointers on what I should be doing correctly? I apologize if the code is hard to read. P.S. I am using a database to store users and their ConnectionIDs.

Edit: I am not receiving any errors when the application is ran. It simply causes the onDisconnected to be called whenever the scripts are finished. When I check if it is a server or client based disconnect it is telling me the client initiated the disconnect.

C# ChatHub:

```
public void createGroupID(string GroupName, int OwnerID)
{
    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, GroupName);
    string query = "INSERT INTO dbo.Collective (GroupName, GroupOwnerID) Select '" + GroupName + "','" + OwnerID + "'";
    ConnC.ExecuteQuery(query);
}

public void getGroupID(string GroupName, string members)
{
    string query = "Select * From dbo.Collective Where GroupName = '" + GroupName + "'";
    int ID = 0;
    int.TryParse(ConnC.GetColumnVal(query, "GroupID"), out ID);

    int mem;
    int.TryParse(members, out mem);

    mapMembers(mem, ID, GroupName);
}

public void mapMembers(int members, int groupid, string groupName)
{
    var item = "";
    if (DisconnectUsers.Count(x => x.UserID == members) == 0)
    {
        List<Borg> memberConnection = ConnectedUsers.Where(u => u.UserID == members).ToList();
        item = memberConnection.Select(u => u.ConnectionId).ToString();
        Groups.Add(item, groupName);
        //Clients.Group(item, groupName);
    }
    else
    {
        List<Borg> memberConnection = DisconnectUsers.Where(u => u.UserID == members).ToList();
        item = memberConnection.Select(u => u.ConnectionId).ToString();
        Groups.Add(item, groupName);
        //Clients.Group(item, groupName);
    }

    if (members != 0)
    {
        string query = "Insert Into dbo.CollectiveMapping (GroupID, MemberID) Select '" + groupid + "'," + members;
        ConnC.ExecuteQuery(query);
    }
}

public void sendGroupMessage(string GroupName, string message)
{
    try
    {
        string strfromUserId = (ConnectedUsers.Where(u => u.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId).Select(u => u.UserID).FirstOrDefault()).ToString();
        int _fromUserId = 0;
        int.TryParse(strfromUserId, out _fromUserId);
        string getgroupid = "Select * From dbo.Collective where GroupName = '" + GroupName + "'";
        int groupid = 0;
        int.TryParse(ConnC.GetColumnVal(getgroupid, "GroupID"), out groupid);

        string countMember = "Select * From dbo.CollectiveMapping Where GroupID = " + groupid + " and MemberID <> " + _fromUserId;
        List <GroupMapping> GroupMap = ConnC.getGroupMappings(countMember);

        List<Borg> FromUsers = ConnectedUsers.Where(u => u.UserID == _fromUserId).ToList();
        List<Borg> ToGroup = (List<Borg>)ConnectedUsers.Where(u => GroupMap.Any(m => m.UserID == u.UserID));

        var UName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
        var item = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);

        if (FromUsers.Count != 0 && ToGroup.Count() != 0)
        {
            foreach (var ToUser in ToGroup)
            {
                // send to                                                                              
                //Chat Title
                Clients.Group(GroupName).addMessage(FromUsers[0].UserName, message);
                //Clients.Group(GroupName).sendGroupMessage(GroupName, FromUsers[0].UserName, GroupName, message);
                //Clients.Client(ToUser.ConnectionId).sendPrivateMessage(GroupName, FromUsers[0].UserName, GroupName, message);
            }

            foreach (var FromUser in FromUsers)
            {
                // send to caller user                                                                                
                //Chat Title
                Clients.Group(GroupName).addMessage(FromUsers[0].UserName, message);
                //Clients.Group(GroupName).sendGroupMessage(GroupName, FromUsers[0].UserName, GroupName, message);
                //Clients.Client(FromUser.ConnectionId).sendPrivateMessage(GroupName, FromUsers[0].UserName, GroupName, message);
            }
            // send to caller user
            //Clients.Caller.sendPrivateMessage(_toUserId.ToString(), FromUsers[0].UserName, message);
            //ChatDB.Instance.SaveChatHistory(_fromUserId, _toUserId, message);
            Messages _MessageDetail = new Messages { FromUserID = _fromUserId, FromUserName = FromUsers[0].UserName, UserID = groupid, UserName = GroupName, Message = message };

            var TUserName = GroupName;
            var FUserName = FromUsers[0].UserName;

            string Query = "Insert Into dbo.HiveMessages (FromUserID, FromUserName,GroupID, UserName, Message, TimeSent)  Select '" + _fromUserId + "','" + FUserName + "','" + groupid + "','" + GroupName + "','" + message + "', GetDate()";
            ConnC.ExecuteQuery(Query);
            AddMessageinCache(_MessageDetail);
        }
    }
    catch { }
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    var t = $("#groupname").val();
    var i = $("[id$=hidCurrentID]").val();
    e.server.createGroupID(t, i);
    //var g = e.server.getGroupID(t).val();
    OpenGroupChatWindow(e,i,t);
}),    
function createGroupChatWindow(e, i, t, n, s) {
    s = "Welcome to the start of your Group.",
    n = $("[id$=hidCurrentUser]").val(),
    $("#chatd").append('<div id="' + t + '"></div>'),
    $('#user-list :selected').each(function (i, selectedelement) {
        var mem = $(selectedelement).val();
        //var mem = members[i].val();
        e.server.getGroupID(t, mem);
        o = $('<a id="' + i + '" class="col-sm-12 bg-succ" >' + t + "<a>"),
        $(o).dblclick(function () { var i = $(this).attr("id"); a != i && OpenGroupChatWindow(e, i, t) });
        $("#group").append(o);
        $("#" + t).chatbox({
            id: t, 
            title: t, 
            user: mem, 
            offset: getNextOffset(), 
            width: 200, 
            messageSent: function (t, n, s) { 
                e.server.sendGroupMessage(t, s), 
                TypingFlag = !0 
            },
            boxClosed: function (e) {
                $("#" + e).remove(); 
                var i = showList.indexOf(e); 
                if (-1 != i) {
                    showList.splice(i, 1), diff = config.width + config.gap;
                    for (var t = i; t < showList.length; t++) 
                        offset = $("#" + showList[t]).chatbox("option", "offset"), $("#" + showList[t])
                            .chatbox("option", "offset", offset - diff)
                }
            }
        });
    });
    $("#" + t).siblings().css("position", "relative"),
    $("#" + t).siblings().append('<div id="typing_' + i + '" style="width:20px; height:20px; display:none; position:absolute; right:14px; top:8px"><img height="20" src="' + srp + 'images/pencil.gif" /></div>'),
    $("#" + t).siblings().find("textarea").on("input", function (t) { 1 == TypingFlag && e.server.sendUserTypingRequest(i), TypingFlag = !1 });
    var a = parseInt($("[id$=hidCurrentID]").val()), o = i;// e.server.requestLastMessage(a, o)
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chat-window">
    <div id="popup-title-bar" style="bottom:0; width: 200px;"> 
        <span class="col-sm-9 txt-primary" style="color: white;">
            <strong>Online Members</strong>
        </span>
        <div id="min-button">
            <i>&plusmn;</i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="popup-box" style="display: none; overflow-y:auto;">
        <div id="on" style="display: block; overflow-y:auto;">
            <span>-Online Users-</span>
        </div>
        <div id="group">
            <a id ="new-group" class="col-sm-12 bg-succ">-New Group-</a>
        </div>
        <div id="off">
            <span>-Offline Users-</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="group-control" style="display: none;">
    <div id="group-title-bar">
        <span class="col-sm-9 txt-primary" style="color: white; width: 375px;">
            <strong>Create A New Group</strong>
        </span>
        <div id="close-group-control" style="font: 25px; right: 0px;">&#x274c;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="group-input">
        <div id="group-name" style="float:left;">
            <label for="groupname" style="display:block">
                <strong>Name your Group</strong>
            </label>
            <textarea placeholder="-Group Name Here-" id="groupname" name="groupname" maxlength="50" style="display: block; resize: none;width: 200px; height:35px; border:3px solid #428bca; padding:4px; font-family:'Times New Roman';"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="submit-group" style="float:right;text-align:center;">
            <label for="submit" style="display:block; right:0px; width:200px; height:35px; text-align:center;" >
                <strong>Create Group</strong>
            </label>
            <input id="submit" style="display:block; right:0px; width:200px; height:35px; text-align:center;" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
        <div id="group-choose" style="display:block;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." style="display:block; width:200px; height:35px;" id="chosenUser" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
            <select style="display: block;" multiple="multiple" id="user-list" class="dropdown-content" name="user-list">
                <option value="" selected style="width:200px; height:35px;">-Select your Group Members-</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide an error log?

Comment: I am not receiving an error when I run a debug for the javascript and my project does not error out as well.

Comment: Is your html inside a form ? In which case the submit button would cause the form to be submitted, the page would be refreshed whilch would disconnect the signalr connexion. If it's the case try to add and event.preventDefault() in the click handler

Comment: It is inside a form! I will look into changing this when I'm back home!

Comment: That did it! Thank you!

Comment: Urgh, you have some horrendous SQL injections issues here...